# Mocking the bean and defining its behavior at context level

Tags: junit, easymock

I have few mocked beans in my configuration which are dependencies of many other beans. 
I want to define its behavior to return null on any of its method invocations irrespective of its input.
I am using easyMock

```
TestClass
{
@Autowired 
ActualClass ac;

public Test()
{
ac.dosometing();
}
}


ActualClass
{

@Autowired
MockedClass mockedObject;

public dosomething()
{

mockedObejct.someMethod(); //i want this to be returned null in any  scenario for the test cases
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
MockedClass mock = createNiceMock(MockedClass.class);
replay(mock);
ac.setMockedClass(mock);
```

The modern version, using JUnit rule and annotations, would be

```
public class MyTest
{
    @Rule
    public EasyMockRule rule = new EasyMockRule(this);

    @Mock(type=MockType.NICE)
    MockedClass mockedObject;

    @TestSubject
    ActualClass ac = new ActualClass();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ac.doSomething();
    }
}

class ActualClass {

    private MockedClass mockedObject;

    public void doSomething()  {
        mockedObject.someMethod();
    }

}

class MockedClass {
    public void someMethod() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it old way my manually injecting the mocked object. I will try this too. it will reduce my effort considerably.